# Increment pointer when Unpacking Variadic Arguments with Lambda

Tags: c++, c++17

I have the following code which has a function `VariadicWrite` and this function accepts a pointer that it can modify by incrementing it to it points to a different memory location depending on how much data is written to it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

template<typename T>
T Read(void* &ptr) noexcept
{
    T result;
    memcpy(&result, ptr, sizeof(result));
    ptr = static_cast<T*>(ptr) + 1;
    return result;
}

template<typename T>
void Write(void* &ptr, T result) noexcept
{
    memcpy(ptr, &result, sizeof(result));
    ptr = static_cast<T*>(ptr) + 1;
}

template<typename... Args>
auto VariadicWrite(void*& ptr, Args&&... args)
{
    (Write(ptr, args), ...); //unpack Args
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    void* ptr = malloc(1024);
    memset(ptr, 0, 1024);
    void* temp = ptr;

    VariadicWrite(ptr, 1, 2, 3);
    
    std::cout<<Read<int>(ptr)<<"\n";
    std::cout<<Read<int>(ptr)<<"\n";
    std::cout<<Read<int>(ptr)<<"\n";

    free(temp);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem here is that the code prints out `0, 0, 0, 0` if I use: `void*& ptr`.
If I do `void* ptr` it prints out `0, 1, 2, 3` but the `ptr` pointer is never incremented.

How can I modify the `ptr` pointer of `VariadicWrite`? I thought that `void*&` would have worked but in this case it doesn't :S

Comment: Please add the `c++` tag to C++ posts in addition to the version tag.

Comment: I've added the tag. Also made the code compilable so everyone can test it.

Comment: That's great, thanks.

Comment: I suspect your code has a UB because the result I got different results. https://godbolt.org/z/YPWMWK

Comment: I don't know your familiarity with c++, but don't use `malloc` and `free` under pretty much all circumstances. Also, prefer smart pointers over raw pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your `VariadicWrite()` call will modify `ptr` to point to the end of your written data.  Then you call `Read()` without resetting the pointer back to the start, so you read zeros from the uninitialized portion of your buffer that follows the data already written.

Insert `ptr = temp;` between the write and read and see if that fixes it.

The reason `void* ptr` does not work is that each call to `Write(ptr, ...)` will increment the local copy of the argument in the scope of the `Write()` function.  The variable `ptr` in `VariadicWrite()` does not change after a call to `Write()` so the next call will use the same value.

If you change to `VariadicWrite(void* ptr, …)` and `Write(void*& ptr, …)`, you might get the behavior you want.  But I would suggest this a bad idea.

As we can see from the bug in your example, knowing if the function will modify the pass-by-reference parameter or not is of critical importance, yet not readily apparent from the code using the function.  This tends to invite bugs just like the one you have created here.  An inconsistent interface, where `VariadicWrite()` does not modify its argument but `Write()` does, will only make it doubly hard to avoid this kind of bug.

Generally, it's better to avoid non-const references because they often result in bugs like this.  I suggest returning the new pointer instead of modifying the argument.

```
template<typename T>
void* Write(void* ptr, const T& arg)
{ 
    return static_cast<T*>(ptr) + 1;
}

template<typename... Args>
void* WriteV(void* ptr, Args&&... args)
{
    ((ptr = Write(ptr, args)), ...);
    return ptr;
}
```

Comment: You presumably mean "return static_cast<T*>(ptr) + 1;"  in Write function.